# EnumSet with complex logic in Java

Tags: java, oop, validation, enums

Let's say I have an enum:

```
enum EnumDemo{
 A1,
 A2,
 A3,

 B1,
 B2,
 B3,

 C1,
 C2,
 C3
}
```

What approach should I use to create enumset that can contain several EnumDemo elements,but all of the should be from one group, e.g.:

{A1, B2, C1}, {B1, C2}, but not {A1, A3, B1, C1}

Any thoughts are appreciated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can keep in each enum element id of a group it belongs to. And create groups of enum based on this id:

```
enum EnumDemo{
 A1(0),
 A2(0),
 A3(0),

 B1(1),
 B2(1),
 B3(1),

 C1(2),
 C2(2),
 C3(2);

 private int groupId;

 private EnumDemo(int groupId) {
   this.groupId = groupId;
 }

 public static Set<EnumDemo> getGroup(int groupId) {
    Set<EnumDemo> group = EnumSet.noneOf(EnumDemo.class);
    for (EnumDemo value : values()) {
      if (value.groupId == groupId) {
        group.add(value);
      }
    }
    return group;
 }
}
```

This approach is good if groups are static and don't change over time. Also you can create enum like `Group` and use it instead of int for id. Also you can change `groupId` of elements dynamically in your app but I'm not sure it's good approach.

Comment: It's kind of odd to use a pre-enum enum for the group.

Comment: It's not odd for me. IMHO it's better than using int.

Comment: `groupId` is declared as an `int`.

Comment: I mean replace `int grpupId` with `Group group`.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `EnumSet.of` method to generate the sets, that would be the easiest and most readable:

```
 Set<EnumDemo> setA = EnumSet.of(EnumDemo.A1, EnumDemo.A2, EnumDemo.A3);
 Set<EnumDemo> setB = EnumSet.of(EnumDemo.B1, EnumDemo.B2, EnumDemo.B3);
 Set<EnumDemo> setB = EnumSet.of(EnumDemo.C1, EnumDemo.C2, EnumDemo.C3);
```

From there you can use `Collections` to generate the different sets you want using union or difference.

If you are looking to avoid having the problem that an `A1` can be added into a set that already contains `A2` you will have to handle this yourself using logic OR by creating three different Enum types (`EnumA`, `EnumB`, `EnumC`) which contain only their respective members.

Answer (score 0):

What about separating them to different `enum` types?

```
public interface EnumDemo {
}

enum AEnumDemo implements EnumDemo { A1, A2, A3 }
enum BEnumDemo implements EnumDemo { B1, B2, B3 }
enum CEnumDemo implements EnumDemo { C1, C2, C3 }
```

Then you can use `EnumSet<? extends EnumDemo>` as the type for your sets.

```
EnumSet<? extends EnumDemo> demos1 = EnumSet.allOf(AEnumDemo.class);
EnumSet<? extends EnumDemo> demos2 = EnumSet.allOf(BEnumDemo.class);
EnumSet<? extends EnumDemo> demos3 = EnumSet.of(AEnumDemo.A1, AEnumDemo.A3);
EnumSet<? extends EnumDemo> demos4 = EnumSet.of(BEnumDemo.B1, BEnumDemo.B2, BEnumDemo.B3);
EnumSet<? extends EnumDemo> demos5 = EnumSet.of(AEnumDemo.A1, BEnumDemo.B2);        // compile error
```